# Challenging Javascript Comparison Issue (always returning false) | tested/researched before posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison

This is my very first post ever so please forgive me for any indiscretions! I am almost at my wits end, as I have been at this for several hours now, I believe to have thoroughly done my research and tried quite a bit of solutions. I am also kind of new at programming but consider myself a quick learner!

In the below code, I am trying to compare the "buttonClicked" variable which gets the this.innerText value from the button that has been clicked on the page to the "triviaAnswer" variable which receives its value the from array "arrayOfTrivias[j].answer" which pulls its value from the current index object in the triviaArray.

Even though I can console.log both the values and they both show to be the same value, whenever they hit my if statement, all buttons will either return a false match (even the button that matches) to the "triviaAnswer" or a true match (even buttons that don't match) to the "triviaAnswer" depending on the comparison property being ran.

I have tried the following with no success (although I could have missed something!)

~single/both vars: `toString()`, `indexOf`, `typeOf`

~operators: `===`, `==`, `.eq()`

~passing both variables into blank strings for comparison

~switching the variable's placement in the comparison

My goal is to get the string value from the button clicked and see if it matches the 'triviaAnswer'.

All the code is mine (except for the obvious CDN links).

Any and all help is most certainly appreciated! If you happen to solve this issue, please explain how you found the solution, as I would like to learn from this experience! :-)

The comparison issue happens in the "On-Click Events" section.

Here is my code:

**JavaScript**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //This is the array we will use to store our trivia objects.
  var triviaArray = [];

  /**
   * Set the start of the array. We will also use this to keep track of our 
   * place is the array.
   * Set it to minus so we can go to the first objext (0) in the array when we 
   * begin.
   */
   var j = -1;

  //Countdown timer variables
  var countdownNumber = 60;
  var intervalId;

  //button trackers
  var buttonClicked;

  //comparison variables
  var triviaAnswer; 

  //score variables
  var correctAnswers = 0;
  var incorrectAnswers = 0;
  var noAnswers = 0;

  var triviaObj1 = {
   question: "What is the highest grossing anime film worldwide?",
   options: ["Spirited Away", "Howl's Moving Castle", "Your Name", "Pokemon The Movie"],
   answer: "Your Name" 
  }
  var triviaObj2 = {
    question: "What is an Otaku?",
    options: ["A type of sushi", "A type of anime fan", "A type of bullet train", "A type of bonsai"],
    answer: "A type of anime fan" 
  }  
  var triviaObj3 = {
    question: "What is historically the most popular professional sport in Japan?",
    options: ["Baseball", "Basketball", "Sumo Wrestling", "Marital Arts"],
    answer: "Baseball" 
  }
  triviaArray = [triviaObj1, triviaObj2, triviaObj3]; 

  $("#startButton").on("click", function() {
    // pass the array of triviaObjects to the triviaGenerator
    triviaGenerator(triviaArray);

    //Start the countdown/timer
    countdownTimer();

    //Hide start button afterward pressed, we won't need it anymore
    $("#startButton").hide();
  });

  // handles the user button clicks
  $("body").on("click", ".optionButton", function () {
    buttonClicked = this.innerText;
    //if user clicks on an option button, run the following
    if ($(this).parent().attr('id') === "optionsContainer") {
      console.log("buttonClicked:", buttonClicked);
      console.log("triviaAnswer:", triviaAnswer);
      //Run the comparison, check the buttons text and the "answer" from the 
      object. StackOverflow "Problem If Statement Here"
      if (buttonClicked == triviaAnswer) {
        alert("CORRECT");
      } else {
        alert("WRONG");
      }
    }
  });

  function countdownTimer() { // this will be our countdown timer.
    intervalId = setInterval(decrement, 1000);
  }

  function decrement() { // The decrement function.
    countdownNumber--;
    $("#countdown").html("<h2>" + countdownNumber + "</h2>");
    if (countdownNumber === 0) {
      timesUp(); //run the gameOver function.
    }
  }

  function timesUp() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    countdownNumber = 60; //reset and restart the countdown.
    countdownTimer();
    triviaGenerator(triviaArray); //move to the next trivia object.
  }

  function triviaGenerator (arr) { // We will use this function to generate our array.
    var arrayOfTrivias = arr;
    j = j + 1; //Go up one in the array (go to the next object in the array)
    j = j % arrayOfTrivias.length; // end of the array ? -> go back to the beginning
    triviaAnswer = arrayOfTrivias[j].answer; //assign the trivia's answer to a global variable so we can do a comparison against the users answer

    //Print the trivia's question to the page 
    //Make sure the div is clear for the insertion of the trivia's question
    $("#questionContainer").text("");

    //Insert the question for the trivia we are on
    var triviaQuestion = arrayOfTrivias[j].question;
    $("#questionContainer").append( "<h2>" + triviaQuestion + "</h2>");

    var optionsArray = arrayOfTrivias[j].options;

    // Loop through the options array for this trivia and print//append them as buttons to the screen.
    $("#optionsContainer").text("");
    for (var i = 0; i < optionsArray.length; i++) {
      $("#optionsContainer").append("<button class='optionButton btn btn-default'>" + "<h2>" + optionsArray[i] + "</h2> </button>");
    }
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Trivia Game</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        Header/Navbar here
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid text-center">
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 left-center">
          <p id="welcomeBanner"> Welcome to the Trivia Page</p>
          <div id="dynamicDiv">
            <button id="startButton" class="btn btn-danger center">
              Start 
            </button>
            <div id="countdown"></div>
            <div id="questionContainer"></div>
            <div id="optionsContainer"></div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="container-fluid text-center footer">
      <p> Footer Text </p>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXT sjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an extra space in the buttonClicked variable.

You can use trim and your condition works :

```
buttonClicked = this.innerText.trim();
if (buttonClicked == triviaAnswer) {

}
```

edited after @Luke Stoward comment

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! You have no idea how many hours I have spent, researching and reviewing my code for a single typo... Thank you!!! It is a crime I can't up vote...

Comment: I think the OP should update the original variable as opposed to conditionally evaluating the trimmed string. Otherwise they will not only have to remember to do this every time, but also perform the trim() operation in every conditional statement. Seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Try comparing both values like this:

```
if (buttonClicked.trim() == triviaAnswer.trim()) {.....
```

Sometimes there is a whitespace somewhere at the end which is cut out by Javascripts trim() function.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! I had no idea! This is such a life savor! Again, it is crime I cannot up vote!

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that when you make a call to `buttonClicked = this.innerText;` the value being retrieved does indeed have some whitespace characters on the end. You can confirm this by logging the length of the variable with `console.log(buttonClicked.length);`

To fix this you must trim the whitespace characters like so

`buttonClicked = buttonClicked.trim();`

I have created this fiddle (with your code) that demonstrates the fix and working program: https://jsfiddle.net/fu3szacb/2/

**Side note:** I would avoid declaring global variables in JavaScript, this is bad practice and can lead to a world of confusion and pain. Better to avoid this when learning the language.

A useful link to provide context on global variables and why they should be avoided. (There are many sources) https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

As everybody said, this could be about whitespace and not trimming and you could try just by

```
buttonClicked = buttonClicked.trim();
```

But I would add that when coming to comparing strings in Javascript you have to be careful with the comparison and usually trim() as well as using the toLowerCase() or toUpperCase() in both variables being compared.

Also, for this case I would never rely on just comparing string because you're repeting the string of the correct and you can make **many typo errors**. If I were you I would use an array of answers every time with numbered answers, so then you only have to retrieve the numbers and compare them, and this is safer and easier.

You can save in each answer variable the number/index of the position with the right answer and if your worry is capturing the number from the HTML, I'm seeing you're using jQuery. You can just hide the number of each option in every option tag as an attribute

```
numberAnswer="2"
```

and get it with

```
clickedNumberAnswer = $(this).attr('numberAnswer')
```

just below the line

```
if ($(this).parent().attr('id') === "optionsContainer") {
```

so the comparison becomes

```
if(clickedNumberAnswer == triviaAnswer)
```

It would be very strange now to have problems with whitespace and the case-sensitive issues are impossible. Now the triviaAnswer should contain a number and, if my memory is good enough, Javascript converts automatically when comparing "2" == 2, so it's even better.